# Unable to use JSON input for Terraform a map variable in Azure VM extension setting

Tags: json, azure, terraform

I am creating an SQL extension for a Azure Window VM using variable type map.

My module is defined as below :

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "virtual_machine_extension"{
  for_each = var.virtual_machine_extensions
  name = each.value["name"]
  virtual_machine_id = lookup(var.virtual_machine_ids, each.value["virtual_machine_variable_name"], null)
  publisher = each.value["publisher"]
  type = each.value["type"]
  type_handler_version = each.value["type_handler_version"]
  settings = jsonencode(each.value["settings"])
  tags = each.value["virtual_machine_extension_tags"]
}
```

and my variable is defined as below :

```
 variable "virtual_machine_extensions" {
      type = map(object({
       name = string
       virtual_machine_variable_name = string
       publisher = string
       type = string
       type_handler_version = string
       settings = any
       virtual_machine_extension_tags = map(string)
     }))
   }

   variable "virtual_machine_ids" {
     type    = map(string)
     default = {}
   }
```

virtual_machine_ids will have a list of virtual machines and their corresponding ids passed to it from the main file

My tfvars file looks like this :

```
   virtual_machine_extensions = {
  virtual_machine_extension_sql ={
    name = "vmsqlext"   #Required
    virtual_machine_variable_name = "windows_virtual_machine1"  
    publisher = "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management"  
    type = "SqlIaaSAgent" 
    type_handler_version = "1.2" 
    settings =<<SETTINGS
    {
      "AutoTelemetrySettings": {
        "Region": "West Europe"
      },
      "AutoPatchingSettings": {
        "PatchCategory": "WindowsMandatoryUpdates",
        "Enable": true,
        "DayOfWeek": "Sunday",
        "MaintenanceWindowStartingHour": "2",
        "MaintenanceWindowDuration": "60"
      },
      "KeyVaultCredentialSettings": {
        "Enable": false,
        "CredentialName": ""
      },
      "ServerConfigurationsManagementSettings": {
        "SQLConnectivityUpdateSettings": {
          "ConnectivityType": "Public",
          "Port": "1433"
        },
        "SQLWorkloadTypeUpdateSettings": {
          "SQLWorkloadType": "GENERAL"
        },
        "AdditionalFeaturesServerConfigurations": {
          "IsRServicesEnabled": "true"
        },
        "protectedSettings": {}
      }
    }
    SETTINGS
    
    virtual_machine_extension_tags = {
      applicationName = "Windows VM Extension"
      approver        = "IT Infrastructure"
    }
  }
}
```

I am receiving the below error when I run apply:

```
Error: unable to parse settings: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]interface {}
```

A screenshot of the same:
[image]

understand that the issue is coming because the JSON input is not getting read properly , I tried running the code by using <<EOF EOF instead of <<SETTING SETTING as well but it's still throwing the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have assigned to `var.virtual_machine_extensions.settings` a string that already contains JSON, and then in your main configuration you've passed that string to Terraform's `jsonencode` function which means that you are assigning a string containing a JSON serialization of a string containing JSON.

It's unfortunate that the provider just passes through the underlying Go JSON parser's error message here, making it unclear exactly what's going on by using Go type system terminology instead of JSON terminology, but what this really means is that the provider is expecting a JSON object, but you've assigned a JSON string instead.

The solution is to remove the `jsonencode` call and just assign your string directly to `settings`, because that string already contains a valid JSON object and so does not need any further encoding:

```
  settings = each.value.settings
```